# Ghidra: How to display the contents of an array

Tags: ghidra

I have a long array in a program. I can see the contents of the array in the left view but it is not in a useful format. Is it possible to use ghidra to print the array in a copy-paste friendly format (e.g. `[var0, var1, var3 ...]`)

Comment: Select the array -> Right click -> copy special -> Byte String

Comment: what do you mean by "left view"? array can be viewed in copy-past friendly format in the decompiler view.